# what is difference between -> and => in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

This is the code where we have used -> and => .

But I always get confused, while writing code at that time which one to use and where.

So seeking its logic to easily remember it.

```
   $quan= $request->all();
   ChaiExl::create(['date'=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($quan['dt'])),'quantity'=>$quan['quan']]);

return view('edit',['row'=>$row]);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 17):

`->` and `=>` are both operators.

The difference is that `=>` is the assign operator that is used while creating an array.

For example: 
`array(key => value, key2 => value2)`

And
`->` is the access operator. It accesses an object's value

Comment: Thanks. It Helped.

Answer (score 4):

This is PHP syntax, not laravel specifics.

=> is for setting values in arrays:

```
$foobar = array(
    'bar' => 'something',
    'foo' => 222
);
```

or

```
$foobar = [
    'bar' => 'something',
    'foo' => 222
];
```

-> is used for calling class methods and properties:

```
class MyClass {

   public $bar = 'something';

   public function foo() {

   }

}
$foobar = new MyClass();
$foobar->foo();
echo $foobar->bar;
```

Answer (score 2):

=> is used in associative array key value assignment. look below:

```
array(
key  => value,
key2 => value2,
key3 => value3,
...
```

)

-> is used to access an object method or property. Example:

```
$object->method() or $object->var1
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to access a method from a class you will use -> that is

```
$class = new Class;
$class->mymethod();
```

but when you want to declare an array of object pairs you use => that is

```
$property = ('firstproperty', ['second'=>'secondPair','third'=>'thirdPair'])
```